# Capturing data in regex in python 3.11

Tags: python, regex, python-3.11

I've got the regex expression I want to use:

```
\*\*Suggested by \<\@(.*?)\> \(ID\: (.*?)\)\*\*\\n+(.*)$
```

along with a template string:

```
**Suggested by <@1234567890> (ID: 1234567890)**\n\ntesting new idea
```

This works when testing here: https://regex101.com - with a minor caveat (can't seem to disregard multiple new lines)
[image: reference]
however it can be skipped by replacing \n+ with \n\n

When trying to use this in python:

```
import re

user_input = '**Suggested by <@1234567890> (ID: 1234567890)**\n\ntesting new idea'
regex = re.compile(r'\*\*Suggested by \<\@(.*?)\> \(ID\: (.*?)\)\*\*\\n+(.*$)')
content = re.search(regex, user_input)
print(content.group(1))
print(content.group(2))
print(content.group(3))
```

I'm getting this error
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQyZa.png]

I have tried double escaping (which as expected didn't work either)
The regex should work fine I think I might be using the wrong operation?

Comment: Take the `r` out of the pattern specifier.

Comment: Or you can keep the `r` modifier and remove one of the `\ ` in front of the `\n+`  
`regex = re.compile(r'\*\*Suggested by \<\@(.*?)\> \(ID\: (.*?)\)\*\*\n+(.*$)')`.   With the `r` modifier, the combination `\\n+` is telling regex to look for a literal backslash, and then 1 or more literal character 'n'

Comment: There's no need to escape the following characters: `<@>`

Comment: @JonSG It's almost always easier to use a raw string for regular expressions.

Comment: @Barmar I agree though they had a string that was not in alignment with that strategy and removing the raw specifier was the easiest fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group the *\\n*, and then apply the +  quantifier.

```
(?:\\n)+
```

```
\*\*Suggested by \<\@(.*?)\> \(ID\: (.*?)\)\*\*(?:\\n)+(.*)$
```